How to identify duplicate values in SQL
I'm trying to find duplicates being generated in a particular dataset
My orginal query is
SELECT 
    b.admidate, a.token_person_id,
    COUNT (DISTINCT(a.token_person_id)) AS patientCount
FROM 
    new_alzheimers_agegroup2 a
LEFT JOIN
    inpatient_mapping b ON b.token_person_id = a.token_person_id 
                        AND a.indexdate = b.disdate
ORDER BY 
    a.token_person_id

But I'm finding 1500 duplicates compared to the raw data. How do I build a query that will find duplicates?

Are you using MySQL?  Can you edit your question and show us proper sample input table data?

DISTINCT is not a function, it's a set quantifier. Simply write COUNT(DISTINCT a.token_person_id) to make code clearer.

To identify duplicates in your dataset, you can write a query that groups by the columns you suspect are causing duplicates and then counts the occurrences. If the count of occurrences is greater than 1, then you have duplicates.
SELECT 
    b.admidate, 
    a.token_person_id,
    COUNT(*) AS occurrenceCount
FROM 
    new_alzheimers_agegroup2 a
LEFT JOIN
    inpatient_mapping b ON b.token_person_id = a.token_person_id 
                        AND a.indexdate = b.disdate
GROUP BY 
    b.admidate, 
    a.token_person_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    occurrenceCount DESC;

